# Defining and Multiplying matrices in numpy (python)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use numpy and i couldn't figure out how to properly define a `n by n` matrix in numpy.
I've used the `numpy.zeros(n,n)`... but I'm not really sure if it is ok.

is it correct to use numpy like this?
im trying to get `(matrix^T * vector) - vector`.

```
matrix = np.zeros((n,n))
start =  [(1/float(n)) for _ in range(n)]
vector = np.array(start)
newvector = np.dot(np.transpose(matrix) , vector)
ans=  np.subtract(newvector , vector)
```

I'm asking this because im getting the wrong results and im not sure where is my problem

Comment: If you multiply a zero matrix by any vector, you get a null-vector. Hence, I suppose `ans` has entries all equal to `-1/n`, which would be consistent with the code you post. Please give the result of your code and what you expect it to be!

Comment: I don't see any problem, the code seems ok

Answer (score 2):

To define a matrix in `numpy`, you have several choices:

- `numpy.zeros` defines a matrix filled with zeros.
- `numpy.ones` defines a matrix filled with ones.
- `numpy.array` defines a matrix based on something else (a list, for example)
- `numpy.empty` defines a matrix without assigning values to it (so it contains what currently is in memory a the place it was allocated).

All those functions use as first argument a tuple with the dimensions of the matrix. This is why parenthesis are doubled.

With `numpy`, you can use any usual operator (+, -, * /, **), which are performed elementwise.

To perform matrix multiplication, you need to use `numpy.dot` function.

You can then wirte you function as:

```
n = 10
matrix = numpy.zeros((n,n))
vector =  numpy.ones(n) / n
newvector = numpy.dot(matrix.T, vector)
ans = newvector - vector
```

But I suppose that `matrix` should be something else than a matrix of zeros, or the transpose operation isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are right how you to use numpy. To ease the usage I would write the start vector in a different way and use object methods to calculate the desired values.

```
n = 10

matrix = np.zeros((n, n))
vector = np.ones((n,)) * 1.0/n
new_vector = matrix.T.dot(vector)
ans = new_vector - vector

print ans

>>> [-0.1 -0.1 -0.1 -0.1 -0.1 -0.1 -0.1 -0.1 -0.1 -0.1]
```

The output should be correct (Matrix times vector should be a vector full of zeros minus one devided by ten, voila). I'm quite not sure about the general form of an NxM matrix and the usage of transpose (that would need another minute to think about ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @CharlesBrunet, there is a specialized class for mathematical matrices where `A*B` is the standard matrix multiplication (as opposed to element-wise).

## [numpy.matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)

> Returns a matrix from an array-like object, or from a string of data. A matrix is a specialized 2-D array that retains its 2-D nature through operations. It has certain special operators, such as * (matrix multiplication) and ** (matrix power).

Creation examples from the docs:

```
>>> a = numpy.matrix('1 2; 3 4')
>>> print a
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
>>> numpy.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
matrix([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])
```